# Datetime format sorting issue in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, datetime

I have a sorting issue in my project. After sorting I got a result like this in the image
[image: Here is the issue]

```
  <td className="dashboard_table-cell" title={'Created Date: ' + Queue.CreatedDate}>{Queue.CreatedDate}</td>
```

what format will I apply to my code to display the correct sorting order?

Comment: maybe you can try format into ISO string "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.MMMZ"

Comment: what library do you use to make the table?

Comment: it's just a HTML table

Comment: @JeeMok can you show me an example?

Comment: @MilyAlfrad can you give me one example of `Queue.CreatedDate`

Comment: @JeeMok "6/13/2016 7:21:33 AM" just same as in display

Comment: @MilyAlfrad you can try `new Date(Queue.CreatedDate).toISOString()`

Comment: @JeeMok I tried this, but it doesn't work..

Comment: @MilyAlfrad what does it show? and which date isn't working

Answer (score 2):

I found it in my own way,

```
 sort(event){
            if(event.target.id === 'CreatedDate'){
            gridData = _.orderBy(gridData, (o) => moment(o[event.target.id])._d, 
      order[event.target.id] ? 'asc' : 'desc');
            }
   else
        gridData = _.orderBy(gridData, (o) => typeof o[event.target.id] === 'string' ? o[event.target.id].trim().toLowerCase() : o[event.target.id], order[event.target.id] ? 'asc' : 'desc');
    }

     <th id="CreatedDate" className="dashboard_table-head" onClick={this.sort}>Created Date {order.CreatedDate ? <i id="CreatedDate" className="fa fa-sort-asc" /> : <i id="CreatedDate" className="fa fa-sort-desc" />}</th>
    ..............................................................
     <td className="dashboard_table-cell" title={'Created Date: ' + Queue.CreatedDate}>{moment(Queue.CreatedDate).format('MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm:ss')}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try sort by time like

```
createdDate.getTime()
```

so for every date, you will have you will compare 
   `createdDate.getTime()` of each item.

for every `Date()` the value we get from `.getTime()` will be unique and be incrementing.